# Auto scrolling issue

Tags: windows-7, scrolling

I don't know and I cannot solve too.

My desktop PC scrolls automatically without any of my instruction to do so in the middle of anything it starts scrolling and this thing making me to go mad. when I am typing a document searching for a web or in FB / whatever application I am at, it scrolls and make me frustrate then I need to go back to desktop and should press any key mostly <kbd>F5</kbd> then it stops scrolling for a while and after few seconds it again starts to scroll. Please help me in solving this.

OS: Windows 7 32 Bit

**Edit:**

As instructed in comments I unplugged the mouse and even after unplugging the problem exists and also I tried re-installing mouse device too, still the problem exist

Comment: It could be your mouse. What is the scrolling behavior like when you actually want to scroll, is it normal?

Comment: Everything is normal until it auto scroll even know when I am commenting it scrolled twice .

Comment: Unplug the mouse and then start typing/doing whatever. Does it still occur?

Comment: I did and it didn't occur but I cannot confirm mouse as the issue coz sometime it stays without scrolling for long time, amazingly it didn't scroll even once when typing this comment .

Comment: I did hear of cases where strange scrolling behavior occurred because a static charge built up inside the mouse. Leave it unplugged for a while and click the buttons. Then plug it back in and test.

Comment: I tested unplugging mouse again and yes now it scrolled too :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26939/discussion-between-mc10-and-dh47).

Comment: Have you tried turning off Autoscroll?  Have you tried going to Mouse settings in the Control Panel and setting it to slow (under device settings-Scroll)?  What happens when you try using a different mouse?

Comment: Honestly, the only thing I've ever seen like this when a coworker plugged an extra mouse into the back of another guy's computer but kept it on his desk to sporadically move or flick the scroll wheel. It went on quite a while because the guy just thought his mouse was malfunctioning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after lot of struggle I solved  this issue it was not mouse but *keyboard* causing this issue of auto scroll.

After failing attempts of the things mentioned in answers and comments I also put on Windows 7 OS thinking if any virus causing this will be removed but even after installing OS the issue tortured me.

After some other attempts I unplugged mouse and keyboard individually and plugged in keyboard and mouse of my friend's

```
My mouse and My Keyboard : Fail 

Friends mouse and My Keyboard : Fail 

My mouse and Friends Keyboard : Pass

Friends mouse and Friends Keyboard : Pass
```

So I recognized the problem was with my keyboard.

Comment: Did your keyboard have any special keys/knobs like suggested in Gargantubrain's answer?

Comment: No such special keys its a normal keyboard manufactured by `Microsoft`.
Actually Down arrow Stopped working long back I still yet to find the reason for that.

Comment: Seems to me that the down arrow might be pressed while you don't know it...

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue on my HP laptop, so tried different things from above suggestions but nothing worked. Then tried below steps and I found the exact reason of auto scrolling and also got solution.

1. Open HP Hardware Diagnostics > Input devices testing > test keyboard
2. In this test found that page down key was blinking continuously without even touching.
3. Then searched for disabling the page down key and found below link which solved my issue. https://superuser.com/a/1470545/1015744

I suggest to those who are facing the issue, please test your key board first using hardware diagnostics option and try disabling button which getting clicked automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be helpful to use the process of elimination to see if it's the mouse itself or something else on your machine that is faulty. Do something where this problem occurs, and *disconnect your mouse from your computer*, see if that scrolling starts then, if so; Your mouse is most likely to be the problem. If you have spare mouse try with it, and if it still happens, try reinstalling your mouse drivers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the input but this issue is not only with browser it is in every application as I already stated this in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I would look towards drivers that can impact scrolling, such as Logitech SetPoint, Microsoft Keyboard and mouse center, and also touchpad drivers which can have settings such as scrolling when your touch is against the far side of the pad. For instance, you could reboot into Safe Mode by tapping F8 repeatedly while the computer is booting up, so you see the startup options menu and can choose Safe Mode (with networking, if you want to use the Internet, but see below for caution). This would start your computer with most drivers disabled, so you can immediately eliminate or confirm this without going and uninstalling them individually. I would caution against using the Internet if you see that safe mode also disables any antivirus / antimalware protection you have installed. Safest just to open Word documents or something local that you can check the scrolling in.

Hardware wise, there are a few keyboards with a wheel, lever, knob, or joystick type control which can be set to scroll as one of their functions. If you have any such device on your keyboard, you can try moving it to see if it seems to be more sensitive in one direction (the direction in which you are seeing scrolling issues). It may have gone off center just enough to be sensitive to changes in temperature and humidity in your room, thus the intermittent part of the issue.

Comment: Your response does not offer an answer to the original question and would be better as a comment on the question.

Comment: @albal, for what it's worth, I disagree about this needing to be a comment; any answer to a vague problem will just be a list of debugging steps, just like this answer. I guess it could be useful for future visitors having the same vague problem.

Answer (score 0):

I really suggest u to check your mouse driver and update it to latest version.

I'm using Logitech mouse and was having this erratic problem until I update to Logitech latest driver version and install the Logitech Smooth Scrolling for Chrome.

Check your mouse vendor website to find out more.

Comment: Isn't it resolved already?!?

Answer (score 0):

I have a Logitech wireless mouse.  I was having the most problems in ThunderBird where I'd scroll down a bit, and it would keep going forever on it's own.  When I turned off SetPoint's "smooth scrolling" the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I restarted My PC, changed the keyboard and mouse out and no solution.

What finally fixed my issue?

I pulled all USB items out of the PC restarted and just plugged in the keyboard and mouse.

Comment: OP already knew the problem was the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

First, you update your driver. HP Notebook PCs - Using the TouchPad or ClickPad (Windows 10).Disable the scrolling in the settings shown on the document above, and test if that would stop the auto scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Today this happened to me too. (Win7 64 bit)
While disabeling some services in the service manager, suddenly the window starts scrolling up as if I would have hit the up key or permanently pushing the mouse wheel up. It only affects Windows internal programs though but not external programms like my browser. So I could assume it's not due to mouse or keybord issues.

Solution:
I'm not sure wich services I disabled before but then I also disabled the windows spooler service and the problem was gone.

Of course, I don't know why this happened at all though!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Vikrant Ghorpade's answer (https://superuser.com/a/1634587/929351)

I was unable to install the HP Diagnostic Tool, so I used online keyboard testing tool using Google Chrome browser. It indicated the same issue of PgDown key being hyperactivated. Disabled it using KeyTweak utility.

It is still hyperactive and needs a hardware fix but at least I can work for now.

Answer (score -1):

I had  same problem. With this simple manipulation auto scrolling problem is gone:

1. Control panel > device manager
2. Right click on mouse icon
3. Choose uninstall it
4. Reboot your system.