# How To Disable PageUp and PageDown Keys on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I want to disable PageUp and PageDown keys on Dell Latitude 5590 running Windows 10. This is a work machine that I can't install any third party software on. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/430906/can-i-interchange-my-home-end-keys-with-pageup-pagedown-keys-on-dell-latit) answer requires AutoHotkey.

Isn't there a way to do this in regedit.exe?

Comment: Do you not have admin rights, or are you just not allowed to install anything?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Warning**: this solution involves editing the registry.

Open regedit.exe and browse to `"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout\"`. Add a new binary key value and name it `"Scancode Map"` (if it already exists, just edit it to change the values which are not zeroes). Enter:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
03 00 00 00 00 00 49 E0
00 00 51 E0 00 00 00 00
```

Reboot and the PgUp and PgDn keys should be disabled.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

This utility does the same thing as the registry edit in the answer from @johnbchron, but it adds a UI to make finding the correct key a little easier.

- [SharpKeys on GitHub](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys)
- [SharpKeys FAQ on the author's blog](https://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/faq.htm)